# Paginate events without setting expiry date

Tags: pagination

Is there a way to paginate events entries without setting an expiry date for each entry? So I currently have:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('eventsEntry').limit(3).orderBy('eventDate') as pageInfo, upcomingEvents %}

{% for event in upcomingEvents if event.eventDate >= now %}     
...
{% endfor %}
```

But this will include past events in the loop but not show them when output. Which results in empty 'slots' on the first page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include an extra parameter in your initial query to only fetch event entries for events in the future and remove the conditional test from the `for` loop.

Currently you are fetching all event entries and paginating those, but only displaying event entries where the `eventDate` is in the future.

Try this instead:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('eventsEntry').limit(3).eventDate('>=' ~ (now | date('Y-m-d H:i'))).orderBy('eventDate') as pageInfo, upcomingEvents %}

{% for event in upcomingEvents %}     
...
{% endfor %}
```